# Hash of integers in python

Tags: python, hash, python-internals

I understand that hash of an immutable object is an integer representation of that object which is unique within the process's lifetime.

Hash of an integer object is the same as the value held by the integer. For example,

```
>>> int(1000).__hash__()
1000
```

But when the integer grows big enough, above principle breaks after a certain threshold as it seems. Its value seems to be rolled with in some limit.

```
>>> int(10000000000000000).__hash__()
10000000000000000
>>> int(100000000000000000).__hash__()
100000000000000000
>>> int(1000000000000000000).__hash__()
1000000000000000000
>>> int(10000000000000000000).__hash__()
776627963145224196
```

Two questions:

1. What is the limit? What is the integer-space that hash table covers?
2. How is the hash value calculated for an integer exceeding the above limit?

System information:

```
Linux lap-0179 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Python  interpreter:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
```

Comment: The value returned by `__hash__` is used for adding the `int` as a `dict` key; it's not really related to the value returned by `id`, which is the unique value representing the `int` object.

Comment: Hash values should remain *unchanged* during the life of an object, but multiple objects could have the same hash value at the same time. (Hash tables have techniques for dealing with such hash collisions.) The value returned by `id`, on the other hand, *is* unique for the lifetime of the *object* (not the process, since the Python process can reuse the same id for two objects that don't exist at the same time.)

Comment: @chepner isn't different object should have different hash? so why other `int` object have same hash?

Comment: Not sure what to say other than "read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types)"...

Comment: Because there aren't enough possible hashes for all possible objects.

Comment: @sahasrara62, as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__): _The `__hash__()` method should return an integer. The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value_

Comment: Even if you said "every `int` is its own hash", that would use up all possible `int` values as hashes for just the `int`s; you'd have no unique values left to act as hash values for strings, floats, tuples, or any other hashable type.

Comment: @chepner Hilbert's Hotel solved that problem a long time ago already.

Comment: Hilbert's solution will come in handy once Python switches to infinite hash tables in its `dict` implemeantion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is machine and implementation dependent, for CPython on 64-bit machines, the `hash()` for a non-negative integer `n` is computed as `n % k` with `k = (2 ** 61 - 1)` (`= 2305843009213693951`) hence values between `0` and `k - 1` are left as is.

This is empirically evidenced here:

```
k = 2 ** 61 - 1
for i in range(k - 2, k + 2):
    print(i, hash(i), i % k)
# 2305843009213693949 2305843009213693949
# 2305843009213693950 2305843009213693950
# 2305843009213693951 0
# 2305843009213693952 1
```

For the complete ruleset, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types).

Comment: Only the modulus is an implementation detail, though.